# Different behavior of QSqlQueryModel for refresing data after adding and update record

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside2

I've got the QTableView with the menu for adding and editing records. The model is prepared with QSqlQueryModel, as it shows also the associated data (sums of amount) for the records.

After doing the actions I want to refresh the table.
I don't understand why for the edit action it is enough to do the `model.query().exec_()` to see the update, but for the new action, I need to additionally do `model.setQuery(model.query())` to see newly inserted rows.

```py
    def build_model(self):
        self.model = QSqlQueryModel()
        self.model.setQuery("SELECT b.id, b.name, SUM(coalesce(s.amount, 0.00)) as amount\
                            FROM budget AS b\
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN transaction_split as s ON s.id_budget = b.id\
                            GROUP BY b.id\
                            ORDER BY name")
        self.table.setModel(self.model)


    def act_new(self):
        dlg = BudgetEd()
        dlg.dialog.exec()

        self.model.query().exec_()
        self.model.setQuery(self.model.query()) # Why I need to this? to refresh the view

    def act_ed(self):
        # ... retrieve id_
        dlg = BudgetEd(id_)
        dlg.dialog.exec()
        self.model.query().exec_() # or why this works without setting the query in the model again?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided not to use QSqlQueryModel(), as it was conflicting with sqlalchemy queries on Windows (windows locks files for reading).
I implemented my own  TableModel(QAbstractTableModel) as it was a really easy task:

```py
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    sql: text

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = []
        self.sql = None

    def set_sql(self, sql: str):
        self.sql = text(sql)

    def load_data(self):
        sess: session = Session()
        self._data = sess.execute(self.sql).fetchall()
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def set_data(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index: PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
            return value
        if role == Qt.UserRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
            if isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, float):
                return int(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)


    def rowCount(self, parent: PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, parent: PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return len(self._data[0])

# ...
    def act_new(self):
        dlg = AssetEd()
        dlg.dialog.exec()
        self.model.load_data()
```